# PeekMessage and PostMessage usage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a legacy application that I'm maintaining, that calls `PostMessage(NULL,WM_CLOSE,0,0);` at certain places. From looking at the code I'm not able to guess if it is connected to the following (executed in a different thread),

```
MSG msg;
while(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))  {
    if ( msg.message == WM_CLOSE)
    {
        return;
    }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

Earlier it was using some win32 events for synchronizing access between threads. But, now I have revised it to use `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` instead. I wonder if these `PostMessage` and `PeekMessage` were in anyway related to those events. The application also had some `PumpMessage` (which had the implementation cited above) and `StopMessagePump` implementations which I've never used and don't find useful anymore. The application is supposed to run in the background i.e, it does not own or handle any console windows by itself.

I read the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) and I find it hard to comprehend as they refer to PostThreadMessage internally as a special case.

However, in general, what is `PostMessage(NULL,WM_CLOSE,0,0)` capable of doing ?

Comment: `PostMessage(NULL, ...);` goes to the message queue of the thread that calls `PostMessage()`, not to a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with a NULL behaves like `PostThreadMessage`. But always for the current threead. In your situation if there is only one thread, it is just like setting a flag. Even no multithreading happens. No mutex or other special objects are needed.

If there is multithreading than and if there is no window at all, and you don't need any synchronization between such windows with a `PostMessage` and a message loop, you can just use `std::condition_variable` or `std::mutex`.

Instead of the `PostMessage` use `notify_one` or `notify_all`. Instead of the message loop use `wait_for`. (Mutex accordingly)

But be aware if you have a COM STA or similar, you still need a message loop.
You can still use `std::condition_variable` or `std::mutex`, but you should only stop the message loop after all objects you ever created are destroyed and you condition is met!

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I have this `while` loop (that I've shown above) on thread say, t1 and have PostMessage(NULL,WM_CLOSE,0,0) called from a different thread say t2, **will the loop return ?** (given the fact that t1 and t2 are within the same process, and there no console windows, or the COM STA you mentioned, or user interaction via keyboard/mouse action, whatsoever involved here)

Comment: No. Message Queues are per thread. Without using PostThreadMessage t1 will never get the message when t2 uses PostMessage(NULL,....).